# Sublime Text 3 disable SHIFT+Delete copying the selected text

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to disable this behaviour? It's possible in Visual Studio but I would like to change this also on ST3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows/Linux, the Default key bindings map <kbd>Shift+Delete</kbd> to the `cut` command:

```json
{ "keys": ["shift+delete"], "command": "cut" },
```

In order to disable that behaviour, you can select `Preferences > Key Bindings` from the menu, and add the following to the binding to the right hand pane:

```json
{ "keys": ["shift+delete"], "command": "noop" },
```

Alternately you can replace `noop` with some other command that you would rather perform in this case instead, should you want to use the key for something else.

Comment: Thanks, I bound it to `right_delete` which is also the default binding of the delete command: `{ "keys": ["shift+delete"], "command": "right_delete" }`

Answer (score 4):

I think that the original question is not about removing the functionality of <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, but only removing the copy function from it. So I'd like to post my answer here in case somebody would be looking for specifically this.

I found `right_delete`, mentioned in the comments, to be rather inconvenient, because you would need your cursor to be at the beginning of the line in order to work. I found that line deletion is set to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> by default (on Windows), so I just used its macro for <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

So here's the line I added to my `Preferences > Key Bindings`:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+delete"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro"} },
```

This way you don't need to worry about the position of your cursor, as long as it's within the wanted line.